# How to have a Sequence of Union while using buffer-layout?

Tags: serum, deserialization, dex, buffer-layout

I'm trying to create some layouts for serum-dex Slab accounts, where,

```
export class Slab {
  readonly header: SlabHeader;
  readonly nodes: SlabNode[];

  constructor(header: SlabHeader, nodes: SlabNode[]) {
    this.header = header;
    this.nodes = nodes;
  }
}
```

```
export type SlabHeader = {
  bumpIndex: number;
  _bumpIndexPadding: Uint8Array;
  freeListLength: number;
  ...
};

export type SlabNode =
  | UninitializedSlabNode
  | InnerSlabNode
  ...;
```

For the layout of SlabNode, I have,

```
const SlabNodeLayout = union(new UnionDiscriminator("tag"), null, "node");

SlabNodeLayout.addVariant(
  0,
  struct<UninitializedSlabNode>([]),
  "uninitializedNode"
);
SlabNodeLayout.addVariant(
  1,
  struct<InnerSlabNode>([
    u32("prefixLen"),
    u128("key"),
    seq(u32(), 2, "children"),
  ]),
  "innerNode"
);
```

But now, for the layout of the `Slab` class, I can't seem to figure out how to have a `Sequence<SlabNode>`?

This is what I'm trying to do,

```
export const SlabLayout = struct<Slab>([
  SlabHeaderLayout,
  seq(
    SlabNodeLayout,
    offset(
      SlabHeaderLayout.layoutFor("bumpIndex"),
      SlabHeaderLayout.offsetOf("bumpIndex") - SlabHeaderLayout.span
    ),
    "nodes"
  )
]);
```

The errors are,

```
Type 'Sequence<LayoutObject>' is not assignable to type 'Layout<SlabHeader | SlabNode[]>'.
  The types returned by 'decode(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'LayoutObject[]' is not assignable to type 'SlabHeader | SlabNode[]'.
```